# Java web.xml page routing

Tags: java, xml, servlets, routes

So here is my problem, I am somewhat new to programming, and now I want to make "web.xml" in Java EE project, to rout every url that contains "/profile/" to a profile page, where depending on the id after "/profile/" it'll show current users data. I have the servlet mapped as below...

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>profile/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But what I am supposed to do in the servlet so I can get the id, and show current users data?
Please give me an advice, or nice resource where I can see how it's done.

Thank you in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks fine for the `web.xml`. In short, if you're using a JAX-RS implementation (e.g. [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)), you should use the `@Path` annotation with `@PathParam` for the parameters, so something like:

```
@Path("/profile")
public class ProfileService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Profile getProfile(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        //...
    }
```

See the [Oracle guide on RESTful Web services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5nc/index.html) for some more background.

Comment: thank you, but is it possible to do it without jersey or it will be really hard

Comment: You could write your own using [HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) but this is harder and loses features.
 
JAX-RS is the standard for RESTful requests (like yours is probably), and Jersey is probably the biggest of these. If you're writing a full web app, maybe an MVC framework (e.g. [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would change tha mapping to the following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/profile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Secondly in `RoutServlet` you should have a the following code to get the `userId`

`int userId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("userId"));`

And finally any URL's that sends a request to `RoutServlet` should look like this

`http://someurl.com/profile?userId=//someId`

This way you can let `RoutServlet` retrieve all the information of the User depending on what Id is in the GET request.

I would let `RoutServlet` put all the data it retrieves in an `ArrayList<Object> profileData`, redirect to a JSP and retrieve the data there using Expression Language, but I dont know what you use/prefer to display the data.